# HTML Relative path not working PHP

Tags: php, html, relative-path

I have HTML code that is calling php in IE6, problem is when i use relative path, it just opens php file but when i use absolute path, then php code is executed. Both html, and php are in same directory and apache is running.

Below one is working:

```
<form action="http://localhost/welcome.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
</form>
```

Not working:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
```

php code:

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br /> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Actually in both case , i'm double clicking the html file. The absolute path file is working fine, it opens up http://localhost/welcome.php but in 2nd case, it just opens c:/xampp/htdocs/welcome.php.   I don't know what is wrong here? Do i need to add .html setting in conf file.

Comment: @John that's an answer; you should make it one.

Comment: @Jordon Thanks.  I did and added some color to make it understandable.

Answer (score 5):

I expect, in the 2nd case, you're actually running it from a file:/// protocol. This means that it isn't passing through your server at all.

You should never double-click on a file in your explorer, as that will just open it through the filesystem.  None of your PHP will work that way.

---

With the full URL, you're actually making a request to a server.  You'll navigate from whatever file/protocol you're at to a named location:  http://localhost/welcome.php.

With a relative URL, you're starting from your base directory (file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/), and relatively navigating to welcome.php.  This makes your final URL file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/welcome.php.  Since the second one is not rendered by a server... you're not going to get anything useful.

Does this mean you shouldn't use relative URLs?  No, not at all.  This means you should start from your http server.  Set a bookmark.  : )

Comment: I added some clarity here for you.

Comment: Got the answer, If is use http://localhost/wel_input.hml, it is able to take relative path. Thanks so much John, God bless you !

Answer (score 1):

Let the file with the form be: C:\xampp\htdocs\form.html

If you're navigating in an explorer, and clicking on the file, than any link within that file will also default to the file protocol, and not http. Meaning, that the browser will go the location and open the file, and parse it itself without the server.

You must navigate to localhost/form.html and than it will work.

Comment: I don't understand why it works with absolute path and not with relative path.

Comment: exactly what are you typing in the browser in order to open up the file with the form?